# Why is Apache HTTP not offering the best available cipher suite from OpenSSL?

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl, ssl

I am using OpenSSL version 1.0.2k and Apache HTTP version 2.4.27.

Based on [this advice](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-openssl.html) in section “Putting It All Together", I queried OpenSSL for what cipher suites are available as so:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'kEECDH+ECDSA:kEECDH:kEDH:HIGH:+SHA:+RC4:RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP:!kECDH:!CAMELLIA:!IDEA:!SEED'
```

This is the returned list of 39 suites, adding an empty line before and after DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 to make it stand out here for its position in the list:

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256

DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD

DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES128-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
RC4-SHA                 SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
```

So, I added these two directives to my Apache HTTP configuration:

```
SSLCipherSuite kEECDH+ECDSA:kEECDH:kEDH:HIGH:+SHA:+RC4:RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP:!kECDH:!CAMELLIA:!IDEA:!SEED
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

When I use OpenSSL to test this, I expect the most desirable cipher suite to be used (shown at the top of the list above), ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, but instead I see DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 being applied:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8777

SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

Even if I try to insist on the better cipher that’s listed as available via openssl ciphers -v, I still fail:

```
openssl s_client -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 -connect localhost:8777

SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
```

Why? Why does Apache HTTP offer the 1st non-ECDHE cipher suite on the list instead of the one at the top of the list? If the client calling Apache doesn’t know ECDHE cipher suites, I understand, but my client is the same OpenSSl on the server that gave me the list of what’s available!

Comment: Did you configure an ECC/ECDSA certificate (and matching ECC key) on the server? If not, it cannot support any ECDHE-ECDSA ciphersuite. However, with server pref you should get ECDHE-RSA rather than DHE-RSA, at least assuming you provided or that version of Apache defaults the ephemeral aka 'temp' ECDH 'curve', which I don't know and the mod_ssl doc is ambiguous; if you didn't provide it you might try that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you, dave_thompson_085.

I didn't understand most of your advice but your 1st sentence was what I needed to understand that this is simply a matter of getting a new certificate & key made to support ECC (elliptical curve cryptography) instead of the RSA certificate in place now.

Comment: You need an ECC key and cert, specifically an ECC-signing (aka ECDSA) cert, for ECDHE-ECDSA. However you don't need it for ECDHE-RSA; you should be able to get ECDHE-RSA with your existing cert but you don't; the rest of my comment speculates about that part.